# cannot install stylus using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, stylus

I have downloaded the stylus .zip from Github and have placed it into the same directory as the node executable. After that I run the following code:

```
install stylus
```

But I do not get a response. The command prompt reads

```
...
```

Has anybody had this problem installing stylus before? I have Windows. Please help me figure out whats wrong.

**EDIT:**
I have updated my PATH variable as well

Comment: What is this 'install' command? Where are you running this? If you have already downloaded the package, why do you need to 'install' it at all? When downloading node modules, putting they in the same directory as the Node executable is wrong. You put the modules inside a folder called 'node_modules' in the same directory as your application script, not Node itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is recommended to install Node.js packages through [NPM](http://npmjs.org/), like so:

`npm install stylus` - for local usage (for your project)

or

`npm install stylus -g` - install it globally, use it everywhere

Comment: @alessioalex--i just found out that npm is available for windows. problem solved. thanks.